# How to Insert data received from WebSocket in C# without Delay

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, websocket, websocket-sharp

I want to insert the data in database received from WebSocket but I'm getting a delay while inserting.
I'm using `WebSocketSharp()` for WebSocket
the data I'm getting in JSON Format.
The hit count of  `WebS.OnMessage +=(s1,e1)=>` method in 550 times in 1 sec and the data received form websocket is single line getting single lines 500 in 1 sec and that need to be insert less then a 1sec or in millisecond.

data Sample->

```
{"seg":"BSE","currc":"0.012","code":"538610","ltt":"1683171716"}
```

```
WebSocket WebS =new WebSocket("SocketLinkHere");
WebS.OnOpen+=(s1,e1)=>
{
//no need
};
WebS.OnError +=(s1,e1)=>
{
    if(!WebS.IsAlive)
    {
        WebS.close();
        WebS.Connect();
    }
};
WebS.OnClose +=(s1,e1)=>
{
    //errorlist here
};
WebS.OnMessage +=(s1,e1)=>
{
    try
    {
        string result="["+e1.Data+"]";
        SQLEXE(result);//call method to insert result into database
    }
    catch(exception ex){}
};

WebS.Connect();


private void SQLEXE(string result)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(result);
        SqlParameter[] para={
        new SqlParameter("@ltt",dt.Rows[0]["ltt"]),
        new SqlParameter("@code",dt.Rows[0]["code"]),
        new SqlParameter("@currc",dt.Rows[0]["currc"]),
        new SqlParameter("@seg",dt.Rows[0]["seg"])
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(para);
        cmd.executeNonQuery
    }
    catch(Exception error){}
}
```

I need to insert that data in less then 1 sec in database.
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf6gH.png)

Comment: ~500 per second, means about 2ms per insert. Which isn't bad perf given there will be a round trip overhead to the database. Consider batching inserts to reduce overheads.

Comment: How much milliseconds does that executeNonQuery call take?

Comment: when we start it will work properly after a min it well take some time and that delay get increase up to 10 or 15 min.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the correct data types and lengths on the SqlParameters to match the data types and lengths of the related columns in the table, or the parameters of the stored procedure you're calling? If you don't then it can create a new query plan for each request (and query compilation takes time) and eventually blow out the plan cache because you won't be getting any plan reuse.

Comment: There are minor problems in this code but none of it explain delays like that. We need to know what that query does, what the tables and columns look like, what indexes are present and what the query plan shows for whatever happens on the SQL Server in that ExecuteNonQuery call.

Comment: Check the memory usage on your app, maybe it's getting delayed by gc? as someone else suggested, i would probably run the inserts in separate thread, batched by some number of rows. since otherwise the overhead is quite large.

Comment: @siggemannen I also try that way to run this SQLEXE on Different Thread but face some error at run time

Comment: @rene There is a stored procedure which has only insert query in it.

Comment: when you get such delays, what do you see in SSMS Activity monitor? you can click on query and select query plan to see if something is strange

Comment: so it inserts in a single table? No indexes? No triggers? Any other readers / writers for that table? What are the columns for that table? Where is that sql server on the network? Is it close to you or at the other end of the world? Show the insert statement just to be sure you're not overlooking something.

Comment: @siggemannen ok but, is it possible to insert 500 rows in milliseconds one by one?

Comment: Given you're I/O bound, it depends.

Comment: @rene The sql-server setup on local network LAN

Comment: I'm still interested in the answers on my other comment.

Comment: it's tough, but possible, but i don't think it's possible using non-bulk techniques. we do around 20 mils rows per day which is around 50% of your kind of speed, but have far more columns without problems

Comment: @rene I added Table Structure in post please check